# Blender Manual URLs: 2.79 vs 2.8 - Not Found (404) for discontinued features

Tags: documentation

I've noticed recently that the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/) often returns a 404 page since transitioning to 2.8.

For example, if you search on Google for "*blender game engine audio formats*" the top hit is [Sound Actuator — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/sound.html) and this is the URL:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/sound.html

But it leads to a 404 page, presumably because the Blender Game Engine will be discontinued in 2.8. But no explanation is offered to visitors looking for information about BGE features because the manual seems to only show documentation on the latest version.

[image]

If we replace **dev** with **2.79** we get the correct URL:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/sound.html

The issue is made worse by the fact that this button on the page appears to be broken when trying to switch from 2.8 to another version:

[image]

So even though helpful documentation exists for these 2.79 features, people starting from a Google search are prevented from finding that documentation, unless they figure out that they need to manually change that part of the URL. So what I'm wondering is:

- Is this expected to eventually change?
- Are those who maintain the manual aware of this?
- If they aren't aware, who should be notified?